# GParted created 30GB partition with 0.6-1.6GB usage

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted

I have Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon. I intend to install 3 other Linux distros on my SSD, so I installed gparted 0.18 from the package manager. I realized that I cannot resize the root partition with that, so I downloaded the iso of gparted 0.23 available here: http://gparted.org/download.php , I wrote it to a pendrive booted from there and resized the Mint to 30GB and made 3x30GB ext4 partition.

The new partitions should be empty, but they aren't. They contain an empty lost+found folder which I can open only under root shell. According to some forums this is okay by ext filesystems, but I don't remember seeing this folder under the Mint before resizing it. From Mint I got this by checking the properties of an empty drive:

[image: image1]

So 1,6GB space is used.

I opened GParted 0.18 to recreate the partitions, but I got the following message:

[image: Message]

It tells something about GPT signatures, which I don't understand, I ignored the message to check the partition sizes:

[image: image3]

According to gparted 0.18 ~620MB is used, and not 1.6GB.

What should I do to get 3 (really) empty partitions and keep Mint on the 4th?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There's used space on a newly-created partition! What's the deal?

On `ext3/ext4` filesystems, some space is reserved for the `root` user. Why? Rather than explain it myself, I will refer you to [André Paramés' answer on a question over at Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41127), quoting from the `tune2fs` manpage:

> Reserving some number of filesystem blocks for use by privileged processes is done to avoid filesystem fragmentation, and to allow system daemons, such as `syslogd(8)`, to continue to function correctly after non-privileged processes are prevented from writing to the filesystem.

You can check this by using `tune2fs -l`:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2  | grep "Reserved block count"
Reserved block count:     13107
```

*(note: your count will almost certainly be different)*

### Okay, so how do I get this space back?

Use `tune2fs` to change the reserved size:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda2
```

and repeat for `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda4`.

This will change the reserved space to 1%. If you really want it to be *"(really) empty"*, then:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda2 (etc)
```

I would recommend reading the above answer, as well as the [`man tune2fs`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs) before making any decision.

Comment: I set it to 0.5%, about 200MB should be enough to these programs. But what about the error message?

Comment: Hmm strange, I used tune2fs, and now the error message disappeared. Okay then. :D

Comment: Fab! If it resurfaces there's a [question over at Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/486581) about sorting the warning message. If not, don't worry :)

Comment: I found out, it is the pendrive with gparted 0.23. /dev/sdc ... :)

Comment: Aha! Well figured out and thanks for the follow-up :)